# Is there any API which can detect GPS location is changed in the iPhone native application?

Tags: iphone, ios4, gps, native-methods

I want to show gps coordinates in the `Label`, is there any default API which can observe/detect that GPS location is changed,so we that I should be able to take and show new `GPS` location in the `label`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497).